# checkout eclipse project from svn to android studio

Tags: android, svn

I recently installed android studio and wished to work on an eclipse project that is inside an svn server.

I successfully connected with android studio to svn and managed to check out my project.

however, many folder's are missing in the project.

java source files are there, but not the res folder , assets folder 
(maybe others but these are the main two)

perhaps they are hidden? how can I retrieve them ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image: Android Studio Window]

You may have to select the "Project view" option from the dropdown. Please find it in the image.